# Does Rogue absorb skills?

Tags: marvel, rogue

I know that Rogue can absorb “memories” when she touches someone, but that’s a very vague, handwavey term. Does she absorb practical skill sets as well? By that I mean not just the theory but the skills itself. Example- if she touched a martial arts master, does she just know how to throw a punch properly, or can she fight at a master level?

Comment: I'm unsure how this question isn't a dupe of [What is the true extent of Rogue's Power](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165905/what-is-the-true-extent-of-rogues-power/165916#165916) as per this ruling on meta _[If one question covers a subset of the other, the more specific version should be closed as a duplicate of the broader one.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4749/68872)_

Comment: @Edlothiad that question asks nor answers anything related to this, even though the title sounds like it would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [her profile on Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/rogue/in-comics) (emphasis mine):

> Rogue's mutant ability requires skin-to-skin contact to absorb *memories*, powers, personality traits, *physical talents*, and strength.

The combination of memories + physical talents indicates to me that, were she to touch a martial arts master, she would be able to fight at that master's level, *as if she were that master*.

Comment: It may be worthy of note that (based on various comments made over the years) a fair part of her training has been spent learning to maintain control of her mind when she picks up someone else's memories, etc. This might serve to limit her ability to fight as that master would. (At the least, it provides an "out" if they don't *want* her to for the purposes of the current story)

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, she does.

It's implicit in the fact that she absorbs people's memories as well as their powers, as stated in her bio in the [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z #9](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A-Z_Vol_1_9).

[image]

As a practical example, in [Contest of Champions II #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Contest_of_Champions_II_Vol_1_5), the [Brood Queen](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Brood_Queen) took control of Rogue's body, and used it to absorb the powers of several heroes, including Captain America and the Hulk.

[image]

[image]

Later in the same issue, she was shown using the Hulk's strength in concert with Captain America's "martial prowess", in order to judo throw the Thing to the ground.

[image]